# Cost of UK visa in Netherlands for a South African citizen?

Tags: visas, uk, south-african-citizens

I am an Au Pair in the Netherlands and want to go visit family in the UK. How much would a visa cost me? And will I be able to apply from Netherlands as I can't apply from home country (South Africa)

Comment: Doesn't the `costs` or `price` tag cover "cost of a visa"? My tag edit revert came with no explanatory comment.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.gov.uk/visa-fees

"Use this tool to work out the cost of your UK visa application."

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on it, as it still doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

A visitors visa is €200 in total - there's a compulsory courier fee as well as the visa fee :/ Iv JUST been through the process with the same criteria as you. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a source for this?